# Selection from Microsoft Word To Outlook New Email using VBA

Tags: vba, outlook, ms-word

I tried this Microsoft Word Macro to paste the Selection I've done into a new email, but when I do it in HTML format, while there is not `<br>` at the end of each paragraph, the result is the sentence word by word without carriage return.

Example:

Text1

Text2

Text3

I get:

Text1 Text2 Text3

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

Set rng = ActiveDocument.Range(Start:=Selection.Start, End:=Selection.End)

Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(olMailItem)

On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .Display
    .To = "to@email.com"
    .CC = "cc@email.com"
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = Date
    .BodyFormat = olFormatHTML
    .HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><font face=""calibri"" style=""font-size:11pt;""><br>" & rng & _
"<br><br></body>" & _
"Best Reagrds" & _
         .HTMLBody & "</font>"
    .Text
```

Comment: One way to solve this might to use a textbox. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45362791/vba-email-loop-for-excel-reporting/45363726#45363726

Comment: In Word this doesn't work ! It came Compile error: Sub or Function not defined on Set r = Range ("B1)

Comment: Right -- that code was made for Excel modules.

Answer (score 0):

try this in your code (untested)

```
dim sen as variant


.HTMLBody = "<HTML><body><font face=""calibri"" style=""font-size:11pt;""><br>"

for each sen in rng.sentences
    .htmlbody = .htmlbody & sen & "<br>"     ' may have to be sen.text
next sen

....
```

Comment: Very good. This is working well. I also added bullets in HTML code.  .HTMLbody = .HTMLbody & "<li>" & sen & "</li><br>" but I miss the signature. It happears for a while but at the end it is not anymore.

Comment: I also change for rng.Sentences to rng.Paragraphs that is much better, while in the sentence sometime is used the dot to do not close the period but just to make a comment later on. So Paragraph is much better but still missing signature.